# Shabbos Shemoneh Esrei specifics stay in

Tags: tefilla, shabbat

Why do some very specific phrases like "Somech noflim, rofei cholim, u'matir assurim" stay in at the beginning of Shabbos Shemoneh Esrei while they are removed from later in Shemoneh Esrei?

Is it because it is describing what Hashem does as opposed to a bakashah? Still, I wonder if there is any commentary why this is so.

Comment: Where are they removed from later in Shemoneh Esrei?

Comment: @DoubleAA I assume OP is thinking of רפאינו... not sure about the others.

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya and thanks for this first question. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: Thank you. Yes, Refuaeinu, and while others don't have direct parallels in shemoneh esrei,, they are more specific and personal in nature,. However, now that I am thinking about it, we still say somech noflim and matir assurim in birchos hashachar, so perhaps my question doesn't stand?

Comment: The *korban tamid* of Shabbos has the *kedushah* of the *korban tamid* of the weekday plus the *kedushah* of Shabbos. The first three *berachos* represent this common *kedushah*.

Comment: Thank you - THE GRAPKE